# Align selected face parallel to a specific axis

Tags: modeling, transforms

Does anybody know
how i can align a face to a specific axis?
Like the guy in this video does it.

[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8hEAJjSyuc&feature=player_detailpage#t=150) (link starts at 2:30 rotating happens at 2:35)
All he says is "I rotate it so, that it is parallel to the y-axis."
Already tried google & co for an answer but hadn't any success.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: All he does is translate a bit on the `Z` axis and then flattens the bottom of the cylinder with `S` + `Z` + `0`.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/140/599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while rotating snaps in 5° steps.

<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Mouse-Movement</kbd>

Enabling *Snap during transformation* has the same effect

[image]

Another way would be to scale the vertices of a face, with all vertices of the face selected:

[image]

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Related:

- [Is there an easy way to align two objects on a specific axis?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/is-there-an-easy-way-to-align-two-objects-on-a-specific-axis)
- [Snap_to_Mesh](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh)

Comment: I knew about the first part, but the way he did it, it was instantaneous and without mouse. Your 2nd solution is probably the way he did it. Thank you very much!