# Center (snap) hole in object

Tags: modeling, snapping

Trying to center a hole in a door, on the vertical axis only.

[image]
[image]

What is the fastest way to proceed?

I've read this answer from Cegaton [Can I snap to the center (midpoint) of an edge?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15551/can-i-snap-to-the-center-midpoint-of-an-edge#answer-15567) Someone asked if this this operation could be done if the two sets to be aligned belong to the same object, in edit mode, the answer was positive. However if I do as described, (snap selection to cursor), the hole is collapsed to the 3D cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in 3 stages, that do involve the cursor but in a different manner:

1. Select the outer border vertices of your door and snap you cursor to this selection (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*). This will move the cursor to the center of your door object.
   [image: Step1]
2. Now, select the geometry delimiting your hole.
3. Open the Properties Panel (<kbd>N</kbd>), and copy the XYZ values from the `3D Cursor` location to the `Median` (which represents the center location of your selection). This will move your selection to the cursor, while maintaining the shape of the hole.
   [image: Step 2+3]
   **EDIT**: Or instead of copying values, you can use the snap tool to move the selection to the cursor (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Snap Selection To Cursor (Offset). The offset option makes sure the selection moves while maintaining its shape (thanks @Mr Zak!).

Result: 
[image]

Comment: Yes that indeed works (by copying only X and Y values as I wanted to keep the height), thanks! I'm selecting your answer, but I've also posted my own which uses the snap tool.

Comment: You could simplify step 3 by using `Shift`+`S` > *Selection to Cursor (Offset)* instead of copying values.

Comment: Cool, will have to try that when I get home

Answer (score 3):

I would:

- temporarily *subdivide* one of the edges of the top face,
- set the snap mode to *Vertices*,
- set the pivot to *Individual Origins*
- select the two inner faces as you show on your image,
- <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to grab and move and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to enable snapping, and snap to the upper vertex.
- then dissolve the top vertex (<kbd>X</kbd> -> Dissolve Vertices)

[image]

Here's a cheeky script that lets you mid-align all selected faces, with the Active Face. accepts `x,y,z` as axis comands.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

def distribute_and_align(mode, axis):

    obj = bpy.context.edit_object
    me = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    if mode == 'Align_Mid':

        a = bm.faces.active.calc_center_median()
        amount = getattr(a, axis)

        for f in bm.faces:
            if f == bm.faces.active:
                continue
            if f.select == True:
                p = f.calc_center_median()
                pamount = getattr(p, axis)

                diff = amount - pamount
                for v in f.verts:
                    co = v.co
                    pos = getattr(co, axis)
                    setattr(co, axis, pos+diff)

    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)


distribute_and_align(mode='Align_Mid', axis='z')
```

Comment: That works, but the `Snap onto itself` needs to be turned on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering myself since I've found the most logical solution (though not the fastest).

I wanted to have the median point of the hole faces aligned with the center of the top face. I discovered in the snapping tool [a possibility to mark several points](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html#multiple-snap-targets) (possibly giving more weight to some of them). We can use this possibility this way:

- Select the faces to be aligned (or the vertexes or the edges).
- Activate `Snap` in the 3D view header. Snapping with `Ctrl` key is not sufficient.
- Select `Vertices` for the type of elements to snap to.
- Select `Center` as the part to snap onto the target.
- Activate `Snap onto itself`, else only other objects can be targets.

Now for the actual snapping:

- Activate grab (`G`) and local Y in this case (`Y`+`Y`).
- Hoover over one of the four vertices of the top face. When the snap target is confirmed (circle), press `A` to mark this vertex.
- Repeat the last step for the other 3 vertexes.
- Complete the operation with the mouse left button.

Note that marking only two vertices diagonally opposed would be enough in the present case.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the inset tool to generate the window.

In **Edit Mode** select the front and back faces of the door.

Then press  <kbd>I</kbd>  to activate the **[Inset](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html?highlight=inset)** tool, and drag to change the thickness.

That will generate a set of new faces centered in the middle of the door.

To shape the window use then scale on the Z or X axis. That way you can make sure that your window will remain centered in the axis you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the **perimeter faces** of the door
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to show the Snap Menu
3. Into Snap Menu Click on **Cursor to Selected** (the 3D cursor moves to the center of the selected faces)
4. Select the **perimeter faces** of the window hole
5. Make sure that into **Pivot Point** menu you have selected one option different from **Active element**: with such option active the following steps might fail.
6. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> again for the Snap Menu
7. Into Snap Menu click on **Selection to Cursor (Offset)**

Done.