# aligning top and bottom of two objects

Tags: modeling

I am modelling a large building and want two objects align at the top and bottom. [image][image]

I have tried scaling but this is a very cumbersome process and in the end the objects are never 100% aligned at the top and bottom. So how to align  those two objects at the same top and bottom position ?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/539/snap-object-on-top-of-surface-of-other-object and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/is-there-an-easy-way-to-align-two-objects-on-a-specific-axis. Use snapping while grabbing vertices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use snapping options to do that.

- Set snapping on and choose the closest to vertex option (under the green arrow bellow)

[image]

- Enter *edit mode* for one of the objects
- Select all the vertices
- Then point your mouse to the bottom of the second object and grab <kbd>G</kbd>

[image]

- Now position the 3D cursor to the bottom : select one of the bottom vertices, then <kbd>Shift + S</kbd> and *cursor to selected*

[image]

- Back to *object mode*
- Set the pivot to *3D cursor*
- Then scale <kbd>S</kbd> and point to the top of the second object

[image]