# How to center a cylinder on an existing hole in a mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms

Given a project with many mesh objects which have the wrong size mounting holes, I've created a bored cylinder with the correct bore diameter, which I intend to boolean union in the existing holes.  However, I'm missing how to center the new piece on the existing holes.  There is a nice explanation [align two objects][1]][1] for centering objects, but I don't see how to modify the explanation to my problem.
[Is there an easy way to align two objects on a specific axis?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/is-there-an-easy-way-to-align-two-objects-on-a-specific-axis)
[image: mounting plate and new cylinder]

Comment: Which explanation are you referring to? The link is missing...

Comment: It looks like your first image dissapeared somewhere so there's no information about what explanation was there about. As to your question - would you like to position unattached cylinder to the surface ? Or how to attach it properly ?

Comment: Rellinked the explanation.   The unattached cylinder needs to be centered and located in the mounting hole (left or right) and then a boolean difference to change the size of the mounting hole.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *Edit Mode* select the hole's rim with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*. Then in *Object Mode* select the cylinder and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->Selection to Cursor (Offset).
[image]